# How to put curl command in python?

Tags: python, curl

I have the following curl code:

```
curl -X POST -u "publicKey:secretKey" \
    "https://api.hitbtc.com/api/2/account/transfer" \
    -d "currency=eth&amount=0.01&type=bankToExchange"
```

how to apply the above code to Python?

Best to all

Comment: What have you tried or [researched](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3929826) so far?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module if you want to make the HTTP call via Python, or run that command using the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module. In the latter case you could have issues when parsing the response in terms of headers/body/status code.